# Warning en funcion atoi - Lenguaje C

Tags: c, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LARGO 10

char pedir_arreglo(int arreglo[LARGO]){
    int input;
    for(int i = 0; i<LARGO-1;i++){
        printf("%d Digite un numero: \n",i+1);
        fgets(input,LARGO,stdin);
        arreglo[i] = atoi(input);
    }
}

void imprimir_inverso(int arreglo[LARGO]){
    for(int i = LARGO-1 ;i>=0;i--){
        printf("%c\n",arreglo[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    int arreglo[LARGO];
    pedir_arreglo(arreglo);
    imprimir_inverso(arreglo);
    return 0;

}
```

Al compilar me tira un warning:

> passing argument 1 of 'fgets' makes pointer from integer without a
>   cast  fgets(input,LARGO,stdin);

Estuve buscando en internet por qué podría surgir este problema pero la verdad es que no entiendo mucho porque recién estoy empezando.Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El warning se debe porqué has declarado la variable `input` como `int`, cuando en realidad debería ser de tipo `char[]`.

Solución:

```
char input[10 + 1]; // El +1 para el caracter nulo
for(int i = 0; i<LARGO-1;i++){
        printf("%d Digite un numero: \n",i+1);
        fgets(input,LARGO,stdin);
        arreglo[i] = atoi(input);
    }
```

De este modo, no daría ningún advertencia, debido a que, se le estaría pasando la dirección base (la del primer elemento) del arreglo en ambas funciones (`fgets` y `atoi`).

Sin embargo, el usuario sólo podría ingresar un número hasta 10 dígitos. Una posible solución, es dejar la variable `input` como tipo `int` y pedir la información con la función `scanf`.

Ejemplo:

```
char pedir_arreglo(int arreglo[LARGO]){
    int input;
    for(int i = 0; i<LARGO-1;i++){
        printf("%d Digite un numero: \n",i+1);
        scanf("%d", &input);
        arreglo[i] = input;
    }
}
```

Otra forma de hacerlo, es agregar el `arreglo[i]` directamente como argumento de la función `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d", &arreglo[i]);
```

**Observaciones:**

**1.** Has definido el valor de retorno en la función `pedir_arreglo` como tipo `char`, cuando en realidad no retorna nada y en ningún momento se hace uso del valor que devuelve.

Lo más evidente, es hacer que la función no retorne ningún valor y para lograr esta funcionalidad, se debe especificar la palabra clave `void` en dicha rutina:

```
void pedir_arreglo(int arreglo[LARGO]){
//code
}
```

**2.** No es necesario agregar ningún tamaño al parámetro `arreglo`.

Es decir, este código:

```
void pedir_arreglo(int arreglo[LARGO])
```

Es lo mismo que decir:

```
void pedir_arreglo(int arreglo[])
```

Si te pones a pensar, ambos códigos dan el mismo resultado.

Te lo compruebo de esta forma:

```
void test(int a[], int b[10])
{
    printf("%d = %d\n", sizeof a, sizeof b);
}



int main(void)
{
    int a[10] = {0};
    test(a, a);
    return 0;
}
```

Cualquiera pensaría que el resultado por pantalla es:

```
40 = 40
```

Pero en realidad no es así, la salida verdadera es esta:

```
4 = 4
```

**¿Por qué dio ese resultado?**

Pues esto pasó porqué en realidad el parámetro `a` y `b` son punteros.

Por lo tanto, el código de arriba es equivalente a esto:

```
void test(int* a, int* b)
{
    printf("%d = %d\n", sizeof a, sizeof b);
}
```

Entonces, nos dio 4 bytes, porqué el `sizeof a` nos imprime el tamaño en bytes que ocupa el puntero.

También recalco, que dio como resultado 4 bytes porqué mi máquina es de 32 bits. Si hubiera hecho la prueba en una máquina 64 bits, me daría como resultado 8 bytes.